# Showing multiple images one by one in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding, panel

Which control is suitable for showing the images one by one like photo gallery in WP7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MetroFlow tool from the Coding4Fun Toolkit will help you accomplish that:
http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Getting-Started-with-the-Coding4Fun-toolkit-MetroFlow-Control

Comment: I don't think this control is visually what the asker is looking for.

Comment: yea maybe not exactly, but I thought it was a cool way to implement similar functionality

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you want to stack them and where you are getting them from. For example, you could use a `ListBox` with a custom `DataTemplate`. Or you could use a [StackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) or a [WrapPanel](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-WrapPanel-in-depth) from the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

How about Telerik's RadSlideView control?

http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls.aspx#slideview

Answer (score 0):

If the images are small just use StackPanel:

```
<StackPanel>
  <Image ... />
  <Image ... />
</StackPanel>
```

You can use ListBox as well (you will get Scrolling and Virtualization out of a box):

```
<ListBox>
  <Image ... />
  <Image ... />
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have done, is use the wrap panel control to display the thumbnails of the images in a grid, then when selecting an image, I navigate to a generic page with pretty much just a data bound pivot control with the source bound to my collection of photos. You can set the index of the pivot to whatever the index of the selected photo is in your collection and then swipe between the photos.